# What's the meaning of cached certificate revocation list and online certificate revocation list in X509RevocationMode Enum?

Tags: certificates

In this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509revocationmode?view=netcore-3.1), there are `cached certificate revocation list` and `online certificate revocation list` terms used.
I tried to find what these lists are but could find any human-readable info.

I want to understand where are these cached list stores on my computer (Windows, Linux) and what online list is used during online check (is there any URL from where I can download them)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you search for this yourself?  It's easily googled.  Try https://support.stackpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001076186-How-To-Clear-Local-CRL-and-OCSP-caches and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/how-to-refresh-the-crl-cache-on-windows-vista/ba-p/1128394

Comment: The links you provided are all about the local cache, as i see. Also they mostly contain just some commands, without explanations i need.

Comment: That's what the article you linked is referring to - a local cache for the CRL of a site.  Where else would a cache be located?

Comment: There is info for cached certificate revocation list, but what about online certificate revocation list?

Comment: Well, it's probable my bad English, i can describe my question properly. I see, that local crl cache stores something like links to crls, so when i use offline check it somehow (i also want to understand if crls are already downloaded and `certutil -URLcache CRL` only returns the urls or i'm wrong) uses these crls. Now, i want to understand what crl used while online check?